# Colocar um valor a frente de uma outra tag HTML usando span

Tags: html5

Eu quero fazer o meu currículo e colocar ele no git pages, e
na parte de dados pessoais, eu coloquei por exemplo:

```
Habilitação: B
Estado Civil: Casado
```

Eu cheguei em uma solução que não me agradou muito, peço que se alguém puder me auxiliar a achar uma melhor.

HTML:

```html
<span>Habilitação:</span><span>B</span>
<br>
<span>Estado Civil:</span><span>Casado</span>
```

Comment: e o que gostaria de mudar?

Comment: Na verdade, eu só quero saber se essa é a melhor tag para ser usada nesse contexto. Tenho medo de estar fazendo uma gambiarra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que você está abusando da `<span>`, que aliás só faria sentido caso você queira mudar algo na apresentação de seu conteúdo, mas que também poderia ser representado com uma tag semântica ao seu objetivo. E evite utilizar a `<br>` para quebrar uma linha, quando o que você tem são parágrafos.

```html
<p><strong>Habilitação: </strong>B</p>
<p><strong>Estado Civil: </strong>Casado</p>
```

Para maiores detalhes sobre as tags e o que eles representam, você pode consultar esse artigo.:
[Lista de elementos do HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list)

Comment: Muito obrigado Leandro, era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando.